# Monitoring Data if manually changed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Is there any tool to monitor the Data in SQL Server in case it has been changed manually not through the system.

I want to check if our DB Administrator edited any record manually or not

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is off-topic. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: you can use AFTER UPDATE trigger.

Comment: @Ben the trigger will be fired even if the update happened through the system (ERP System) 
I do not want any update to be through the table.
Update through the system is allowed

Comment: @B001 sorry ... MS SQL server

Comment: @MaciejJureczko sorry i thought my post is clear

Comment: you can insert new records to another (log) table through AFTER UPDATE trigger, and add `updated_by` column to distinguish whether it is updated by the system or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in many ways, but one feature should actually be set up, either on MSSQL Server or mysql server. In the first case, you should switch auditing for specific database. In case you didn't do it before, you can dog the transaction logs: 
https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/read-a-sql-server-transaction-log/ 
But it's time consuming and can bring no conclusive results.
For MySQL there is a plug-in using audit api, delivered by mysql from version 5.5.3. There are number of plug-ins developed, Oracle delivers one with their enterprise solution, percona delivers one, I believe there are others as well.
In this case also, you can dig the bin logs, analyze sql query log (if set up), slow query log (if set up). But again - it is time consuming and actually you may not be able to definitely find 100% proof. 
Only auditing can deliver hard evidence but it must be set up before, not after.
But you must also know, that if you db admin knows passwords of application users, and he can log in to application servers, then he can log to database using that app user, do the changes, and there will be pretty much no way to say it wasn't an app that changed the record (unless there are app roles set up in the database, which can be used only by application).

Comment: Thank you so much for this complete answear.. actually our DBA does not know any user&#39;s password, so it will be a wasting of time if I want to check a huge DB!

Answer (score 0):

You Can create Triggers

Triggers will be fired when a record is inserted, deleted or updated and msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail should be used to send an email alert to a specified email recipient, immediately:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_Pers 
ON Person.Person 
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS 
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                        @profile_name = 'ApexSQLProfile', 
                        @recipients = 'marko.radakovic@apexsql.com' , 
                        @body = 'Data in AdventureWorks2012 is changed', 
                        @subject = 'Your records have been changed' 
GO
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I know the triggers will be fired in both cases (Manually through the tables or officially through the ERP)